# Change the GUI over time in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphics, tkinter, conways-game-of-life

I am building a conway's game of life graphics using Tkinter in {ython.  The game logic and everything else is fine, I just stuck on the last one part of code which I can't figure out even after reading the library.

```
self.after(1000,self.draw(bigThing))
```

Here is the full code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from button import *
import numpy
import test1
import time

class AppFrame(Frame):


def __init__(self,root, buttonlist):
    Frame.__init__(self, root, relief='sunken', width=600, height=600)
    self.gameisrunning = False
    self.buttonlist = buttonlist
    self.root = root

    self.w = Canvas(self,width = 505, height =505)


    self.boulis = []
    for k in range(1,101):
        for i in range(1, 101):

            button = Buttons(self.w, i * 5, k * 5, i * 5 + 5, k * 5 + 5,k ,i,buttonlist)
            self.boulis.append(button)


    self.whole = list(self.chunks(self.boulis, 100))

    self.grid(column =0, columnspan = 4)
    self.w.grid(column = 0)

    clear = Button(self.root,text = "clear")
    clear.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    self.run = Button(self.root,text = "run", command = self.runit)
    self.run.grid(column = 3, row = 1)
    self.root.mainloop()

def runit(self):

    if self.gameisrunning == False:
        self.gameisrunning = True
        self.transformer = self.buttonlist
        while self.gameisrunning == True:
            bigThing = test1.theNextBigThing(self.transformer)
            self.transformer = bigThing
            self.root.after(1000,self.draw, bigThing)


    elif self.gameisrunning == True:
        self.gameisrunning = False


def draw (self, board):
    for k in range (0, 100):
        for i in range (0, 100):
            if board[k + 1][i + 1] == 1:
                self.whole[k][i].activate()
            elif board[k + 1][i + 1] == 0:
                self.whole[k][i].deactivate()

def chunks(self,l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

I changed the structure a bit.  It seems like anything I want to draw under the 'runit' method doesn't work.  I don't know why it happens.  All the other functions in 'runit' work perfectly fine.  Only this didn't work:

```
self.root.after(1000,self.draw(bigThing))
```

Here is my button class:

```
##button.py
from Tkinter import *


class Buttons:

def __init__(self,canvas,bx,by,tx,ty, k, i,buttonlist):
    self.buttonlist = buttonlist
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.rec = canvas.create_rectangle((bx,by,tx,ty),fill = "lightgray",
                                       activefill= 'black', outline = 'lightgray')
    self.canvas.tag_bind(self.rec, "<Button-1>", lambda event: self.callback())
    self.active = False

    self.k = k
    self.i = i

    self.xmin = bx
    self.xmax = tx
    self.ymin = by
    self.ymax = ty
    ##print (bx, by, tx, ty)

def activate(self):
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.rec, fill = 'black')

def deactivate(self):
    self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rec, fill='lightgray')

def callback(self):
    self.activate()
    self.buttonlist[self.k][self.i] = 1
```

Comment: `f()` calls the `f` function immediately. If you want to draw the bigThing in a second then change the `.after` call: `self.root.after(1000, self.draw, bigThing)`

Comment: But the animation still didn't show,  is it because we can't do graphics change after the main loop? Or is it the while loop?

Comment: there are several errors. I've pointed out the obvious one. Yes, you should not use the blocking while loop in the GUI thread. Also, don't call `mainloop()` inside the `__init__()`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I didn't understand how to talk to the GUI.  The while loop was outside of the GUI previously, but it didn't even call the 'while' loop after the 'mainloop'.  Can you talk more specifically how to move it outside and how it works?  I really appreciate it.

Comment: It depends on whether `test1.theNextBigThing()` blocks and if it does then whether it is I/O or CPU constrained. If it does not block then just run the body of the loop using `self.after()`. If it blocks but it does not use C extensions that might hold GIL for too long then you could use a background thread to run it and a `Queue()` to exchange items between the threads, [example](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error since your `AppFrame.__init__` doesn't call the `Frame` superconstructor -- the `AppFrame` object is not a proper `Tk` object as a result. The code in that method seems to be combined with code that should be calling it and the `Frame` declared in it (`self.f`) should actually be `self`:

```
class AppFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, buttonlist):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, relief='sunken', width=600, height=600)
        self.root = root
        self.gameisrunning = False
        self.w = Canvas(self.f, width = 505, height =505)

        # [as before, but with self instead of self.f]
```

It's generally more modular to build your `root` object outside of an application-specific frame (this lets you embed your app in something other than the root):

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry = "1000x1000"
    buttonlist = ... # needs to be filled in
    app = AppFrame(root, buttonlist)

    # ...
```

Comment: Why should we called the <em>Frame</em> superconstructor then?  isn't frame part of the TK object?  Thank you for the time.

Comment: If you don't call the superconstructor, the `AppFrame` instance won't actually be a proper `Frame` instance and thus won't have Tk methods and attributes (like the `tk` attribute in this case).

Comment: I changed the structure as you said, the error is gone but the drawing still didn't work.